# Joining of two tables in SQL

Tags: sql, plsql

I have two tables sys_policy and sys_benefit both can be linked via policy_id. sys_policy has benefit_line like 1,2,3,4,5,6 and sys_benefit has got benefit_line which has amount details. i have to join these two table which should show all benefit_line for a policy_id and whereever record is found in benefit_line display amount_details else display null for other benefit_line please help

I tried normal joins which is not helping for the cause

Comment: Can you edit your question and add some simple data and the expected result https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Also show us your current query attempt.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT p.policy_id, b.benefit_line, 
    CASE WHEN b.policy_id IS NOT NULL THEN b.amount_details ELSE NULL END AS amount_details
FROM sys_policy p
LEFT JOIN sys_benefit b ON p.policy_id = b.policy_id AND p.benefit_line = b.benefit_line
WHERE p.policy_id = [your_policy_id];
```

In this query, I am using a left join to include all benefit lines from sys_policy for a given policy_id, even if there is no corresponding record in sys_benefit. I am then using a case statement to display the amount details if a corresponding record is found in sys_benefit, and NULL otherwise.

Note that you should replace [your_policy_id] with the actual policy ID that you want to query. Also, make sure that the column names and table names in the query match your actual schema.

Comment: This has worked..